# error: request for member `member` in `cur`, which is of non-class type node<int>* Binary Tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, nodes, binary-search-tree

I have a binary tree

```
template<class item_type>
 struct node{
     item_type x;
     node<item_type> *left;
     node<item_type> *right;
 };

 template<class item_type, class param>
 class Tree{
        node<item_type> *root;
 public:
 //functions
```

In some of the functions I use
`node<item_type> *cur = root;`
and traverses through the tree via `cur->left` or `cur->right`
this incurs me the error:

error: request for member Get_Height /*a function  in cur*/, which is of non-class type node* Binary Tree

```
template<class item_type, class param>
int Tree<item_type, param>::Get_Height()
{
    node<item_type> *cur = root;
    while(cur->left!=NULL || cur->right!=NULL)
    {
        if(cur==NULL)
            return 0;
        return max(cur->left.Get_Height(), cur->right.Get_Height())+1;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure *left is of type node* 
According to the error, the function seems to take a pointer to a node, instead of the actual tree so, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: shouldn't it be something like `node<item_type> *left` and similar for right?

Comment: @ShinTakezou I tried that, it didn't work either, though you are correct.

Comment: @Mat added the lines where the errors were found

Comment: @SemicolonExpected I didn't meant to say it was the sol to your problem, sorry; anyway, it seems it's unnecessary, though it looks clearer to me

Comment: You do know the difference between using the dot-operator `.` and the arrow-operator `->` when it comes to structure member access? If you have a pointer to a structure you can't use `.`, and if a non-pointer variable you can't use `->`.

Comment: Also, I don't see any `Get_Height` member function in the `node` structure.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I put it under the commented out area where it says `//functions`

Comment: Well, `cur->left` is a pointer to a *`node`*, not a pointer to a `Tree`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is there anyway I can have the function point to the node instead of the tree without using parameters? I thought it might have worked due to my compiler expecting a pointer to a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cur` is of type `struct node *`, which is a pointer.

so I suspect, it should be `cur->left != NULL` and also, `left` is a pointer as well, so it should be

`return max(cur->left->Get_Height(), cur->right->Get_Height())+1;`

There is something majorly wrong in your code, there is no `Get_Height()` member in the `struct node`.

Comment: It's actually in the `Tree` class, and I due to the specs for the assignment am not allowed to put it in my `node` struct or add a parameter and because my compiler expected a node<int>* I thought it might have worked.

Comment: If you want to recursively call `Get_Height()`, then you might have to pass in the `node<item_type>*` object to it.

Comment: I originally wanted to do that, but my professor said we weren't allowed to change the function calls.